# Condition on Left Join

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying the below queries where TABLE B is empty AND records in TABLEA

```
--This query fetched no records
SELECT TABLEA.COLA,TABLEA.COLB FROM TABLEA 
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB
ON TABLEA.ID=TABLEB.ID
WHERE TABLEB.COL1<>'XYZ'

--This query fetched records .
SELECT COL1 FROM 
(
SELECT TABLEA.COLA,TABLEA.COLB FROM TABLEA 
LEFT JOIN  TABLEB
ON TABLEA.ID=TABLEB.ID
)A WHERE COL1 <>'XYZ'
```

Could you help me why first query didnt return any records though they look same. My understanding of first query is  "I did a left join so if records doesnt exist in tableb, it should be replaced with NULL values. As NULL <>'xyz' all records should be fetched right..

Answer (score 0):

Placing a WHERE condition on the OUTER joined table of an OUTER JOIN effectively renders that join as an INNER JOIN. So, if there are no rows in the outer table which satisfy the condition, then no rows will be returned.

The solution then is to include any such conditions within the join itself. In the example above this is as simple as changing WHERE to AND.

The one condition that *must* be placed in the WHERE  clause is the test for NULL, the so-called exclusion join - I.e. when you actually want to return the inverse set.